# Referencing same object in different sessions

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm building a web based chess in ASP.NET and the idea is to keep information about table (position of pieces, who's turn is it...) in session as an reference to instance of Game class that stores all needed information.

I don't know how to make that Sessions of both players contains reference to same object on the server so that when one player moves, other has in its session information about that move was made.

Is that even a valid way to do it since I want to avoid lots of DB accessing?

Answer (score 0):

Things like "Who's turn is it" needs to kept at the Application level.  So either use a static variable, or use the Application collection.  Personally, I would use a static collection of 'Game' objects.  You'll also need to keep thread-safty in mind, because ALL sessions will have access to the same collection.

Comment: Well, I don't see why "Who's turn is it" needs to be kept at the Application level? Isn't it only important that both players have access to that information regardless where it is?

But u gave me an idea to use Application collection to "share" reference of ones Game to both players!

Comment: There's only going to be 1 turn for two players and it needs to be stored in the "Game" object. Both players will need access to the Game, so the logical place to store it (in memory) would be at the application level. If you don't want to store the information in memory, then use a database.